# Magento 2 : Error after delete "var/generation" directory and flush all cache

Tags: magento2, cache

I am getting below error after performing 2 steps:

1. Flush all cache.
2. Delete `var/generation` directory.

---

```
exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Source class "" for "Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor" generation does not exist.' in /home/ready/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php:185 Stack trace: #0 /home/ready/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php(112): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->tryToLoadSourceClass('Magento\\Framewo...', Object(Magento\Framework\Interception\Code\Generator\Interceptor)) #1 /home/ready/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Autoloader.php(35): Magento\Framework\Code\Generator->generateClass('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Code\Generator\Autoloader->load('Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /home/ready/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): spl_autoload_call('Magento\\Framewo...') #4 /home/ready/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #5 /home/ready/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(130): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#6 /home/ready/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(67): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#7 /home/ready/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #8 /home/ready/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(233): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #9 /home/ready/public_html/index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\\Framewo...')
#10 {main}
```

Comment: Can You Please state What have You done brief @Ashok Ladumor

Comment: try these command may resolve your problem `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Answer (score 1):

Once you delete the generation folder your generated construction will be removed so you need to regenerate that construction

you can generate by following command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for this issue is that the generated classes (Factory,Interceptor, Proxy ) need time to regenerate automatically (if your Magento mode is developer mode). 
We may need to refresh the page several times.

Answer (score 0):

Run below Command, issue will fix

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set  developer

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Then Check it.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because a generation is not able to create. So, you just follow simple two following steps and then check.

1. Flush/Clean all cache.
2. Check `var` folder permission and try to give 777 permission to `var` folder.

Now check, I hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, **check file and folder permission as per Magento recommended** and then need to **recreate intercepter** file

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

Give **777** permission to `var, pub` and `generated` folder by using command given below.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```